# Noob ASM Questions

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm trying to learn a bit of assembly over here, and I need a bit of help from the pros!

test.s:

```
.data
helloworld:
    .asciz "printf test! %i\n"
.text
.globl main
main:
    push $0x40
    push $helloworld
    call printf
    mov $0, %eax
    ret
```

test.working.s:

```
.data
helloworld:
    .asciz "printf test! %i\n"
.text
.globl main
main:
    mov $0x40, %esi
    mov $printf_test, %edi
    mov $0x0, %eax
    call printf
    mov $0, %eax
    ret
```

compile.sh:

```
rm test
gcc test.s -o test -lc
chmod 777 test
./test
```

test.s immediately segfaults. I made test.working.s by using the disassembly window in eclipse and just writing a small C program to print something using printf.

So, questions!

1. Why does `test.s` not work
2. In my C program, main is defined as main(int argc, char ** argv) is it not? Hence shouldn't I need to `pop` twice at the start if I don't need those arguments?
3. In x86-64, I read somewhere that %rax was the 64-bit register, %eax was the 32 bit register, and %ax was the 16 bit register. So does the register look like this:
   `XX XX EE EE RR RR RR RR` (R = 4bits of RAX, E = 4 bits of EAX, X = 4 bits of AX)
   on a little-endian system (1 is represented as 0x01000000, I think...)?
4. GCC wont let me type `pop %eax` or `push %eax`. It will only let me type the 64 bit versions or the 16 bit versions. How do I push the 32 EAX bits of RAX to the stack then? How do I pop just 32 bits?
5. test.working.s (I imagine this is answered in 1, but if not...) calls printf by changing registers, NOT by pushing stuff onto the stack. I presume this is because it is faster? How do you know when to do this and in what order when calling c functions?
6. Will this also work on Windows x86-64? I understand that the operation of printf may be different, but if I clean up and restore the registers after the printf, I should be OK right?
7. How are you supposed to clean up and restore the registers? According to http://www.cs.uaf.edu/2005/fall/cs301/support/x86/, it says that I "must save %esp, %ebp, %esi, %edi". Is that referring to the fact that, when I write a function, these registers must come back out the way they came in, or that I should save them myself before I call a function. It's probably the former, since %esp, but just checking!
8. It's pretty clear that I won't be needing x86-64, especially since I'm just starting, so how do I alter compile.sh for just x86?
9. Does `.asciz` simply mean `.ascii` + `"\0"`?
10. I can return large structs (>64bit) that reside on the stack in C. How is this achieved in assembly?

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Because in 64-bit mode you should be passing the arguments in registers rather on the stack (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/1524450)). Even if that wasn't the case, you don't have a size specifier for `push $0x40`, so it's quite likely that you're only pushing a 16-bit value rather than 32 bits.
2. The top of the stack will contain the return address to wherever the call to `main` came from (e.g. `__libc_start_main`). Below that you'll find `argc` and `argv`. There's no need for you to pop any of those (you *shouldn't* pop any of them since you need to preserve the return address).
3. The 32-bit value 1 would be written as 0x00000001 (most significant nybble to the left), and would be stored as `(low address) 01 00 00 00 (high address)` in a little-endian configuration. Since it's typical to write numbers with the most significant digits first rather than according to how they're stored, it would make sense to write your `RAX` description as `RR RR RR RR EE EE XX XX`, possibly with bit index markers if it's unclear what the order is.
4. 
5. Again, that's the calling convention for 64-bit x86 code, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2538212/1524450).
6. Not without some changes, since the 64-bit calling convention used by Windows [is slightly different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#Microsoft_x64_calling_convention) (the registers used for passing arguments are `RCX, RDX, R8, R9`).
7. By saving them on the stack for example. There are *callee* saved registers and *caller* saved registers.
   The callee (the function being called) must save certain registers and restore them before returning in order to comply with the calling convention. For a 64-bit program on a Linux-type system that would be `RBX, RBP, R12-R15` (on 64-bit Windows this also includes `RSI` and `RDI`).
   The caller (the code calling a function) must consider certain registers volatile (i.e. can be changed by the function) and should save and restore them if it needs their values after the function returns. On a Linux-type system these would be `RAX, RCX, RDX, RSI, RDI, R8-R11`.
8. The GNU assembler should support an `-m32` command-line option to specify that you're assembling 32-bit code.
9. Yes.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Any ideas about 10? Also, if little endian dictates that the least significant bit is in the first byte, are you sure it's not `01 00 00 00`? Wikipedia says big endian means that the least significant bit is on last byte

Comment: That depends on how you view the data. If you had the 32-bit little-endian values 1, 2 in a file and looked at it in a hex editor byte-by-byte you'd see `01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00`. But if you changed the view to dword mode you'd see `00000001 00000002`.

Comment: My suggestion for point 10 would be to compile a small C example with the `-S` option and check the resulting assembly code.

Comment: I thought the reason you left 2 blank was because these arguments were passed as registers. So even though these libc functions use the register passing calling convention, whatever calls main still uses the old one?